# How do I prove this algebraic statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The expression $\frac{r}{pq}$ with $p, q, r$ integer numbers, $p$ and
>   $q$ different of $0$ is always positive if:
>
> I) $\frac{r}{p} > 0$ and $q > 0$
>
> II) $p*q < 0$ and $r$ **not** positive.

I answer that $I$ is true, because and integer multiplied by another integer, is always positive. $(\frac{r}{p}) * (\frac{1}{q}) = + * + = +$(Sign representation)

also, I answer that $II$ is true, because a negative integer multiplied by another negative integer is always positive. $(r) * (p * q) = - * - = + $( Sign representation)

But the correct answer should be only $I$ correct, and $II$ is incorrect, why ?

Comment: Consider the case $r=0$.

Comment: "not positive" does not mean "negative".  "not positive" means "not positive".  0 is not positive

Comment: "integer multiplied by another integer, is always positive"  What?  $-5$ is an integer.  $0$ is an integer .  $(-5)*0 = 0$ is not positive.  ANd neither $\frac pq$ nor $\frac 1q$ are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) is correct because:

$q > 0 \implies \frac 1q > 0$ and $\frac rp > 0$ and $\frac 1q > 0 \implies \frac r{pq} > 0$.

II) is incorrect because

$r$ not positive means $r \le 0$.  If $r= 0$ and $pq < 0$ then $\frac {r}{pq} = 0$.

The basic axioms/props you should have at your fingertips are:

A) If $x> 0$ and $y < z$ then $xy < xz$ and

B) If $y <z$ then $y +  x < z + x$.

As well as i) $0*x = x$ and ii) $-(-x) = x$ and iii) $x*(-y) = (-x)*y = -xy$.

From those you know:

0)  If $ x > 0$ then $x-x > 0 - x$ or $0 > -x$ or $-x >0$ and if $x< 0$ then $x -x < 0 -x = -x$ and so $-x > 0$.

1) If $x> 0$ and $y > 0$ then $xy > x*0 = 0$

2) If $x> 0$ and $y < 0$ then $xy< x*0 = 0$

3) If $x < 0$ and $y < 0$ then $-x>0$ and $-xy < -x*0 = 0$ and so $xy > 0$

4) If $x > 0$ then $x^2 = x^2 > 0$.  And if $x < 0$ then $x^2 = x*x > 0$ and if $x = 0$ then $x^2 = 0*0=0$ so $x^2 > 0$ if $x \ne 0$ and $x^2=0$ if $x = 0$ so $x^2 \ge 0$ with equality holding only if $x = 0$.

5) So $1 = 1^2 > 0$.

6) If $q > 0$ and $q*\frac 1q = 1$ then since $\frac 1q = 0$ would mean $1=q*\frac 1q = 1*0 = 0$ and $\frac 1q < 0$ would mean $1 = q\frac 1q < 0$ and those are both nutty, we must know that $\frac 1q > 0$.